# While converting HTML to PDF in angular content getting cropped

Tags: angular, jspdf, html-to-pdf

Screen content getting cropped in converting HTML to PDF in angular and multiple pages are getting created.

I have tried using jspdf.
Here is my ts code

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {jsPDF} from 'jspdf';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'HTML_JSPDF';


  @ViewChild('htmlTemplate', { static: false })
  htmlTemplate!: ElementRef;


  generatePDF(){
    const doc = new jsPDF();
     
    doc.html(this.htmlTemplate.nativeElement, {
      callback: (pdf) => {
        pdf.save("sample.pdf")
      }
    })
  }
}
```

But PDF is getting created with cropped content whereas, i want all content to be exactly same in PDF as it appears on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

it is a very common problem with jsPDF
what I do to tackle this is
I give height and width in inches to the html element which we want to print,
the height and width should be same as the preferred page size.
for A4 it is (8.3 x 11.7)
for letter it is (8.5 x 11)

```
.a4{
  width: 8.3in;
  height: 11.7in;
}

<div class="a4">
  This is the html to be printed
</div>

 generatePDF(){
    const doc = new jsPDF();
     
    doc.html(this.htmlTemplate.nativeElement, {
      callback: (pdf) => {
        pdf.save("sample.pdf")
      }
    })
  }
```

keep in mind that some css properties might not work with jsPDF
`'auto' values for css properties`,
`shorthand css values`,
`svg images`,
`flex`(sometimes),
`psuedo css(before, after)`

give fix height and width for images.

Comment: that will be helpful for sure

Comment: I have tried this but it is generating extraa blank pages

Comment: create a sandbox of your problem and will see it further

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that when you create the instance using the following code:

const doc = new jsPDF();

It has some default properties, such as the 'A4' format, and your content might not fit inside it. You can change these properties in order to fit the content.

`const doc = new jsPDF( {orientation: 'p',unit: 'mm',format: 'a4',putOnlyUsedFonts:true} )`

Comment: I have tried by changing it but not working

Answer (score 0):

define the page

```
 const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
```

Set Width & Height

```
const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
const pdfHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
doc.html(this.htmlTemplate.nativeElement, {
  width: pdfWidth,
  height: pdfHeight,
  callback: (pdf) => {
    pdf.save("sample.pdf");
  }
});
```

or use html2canvas

```
html2canvas(this.htmlTemplate.nativeElement).then(canvas => {
  const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  const pageHeight = 295;
  const imgWidth = canvas.width * pageHeight / canvas.height;
  const imgHeight = pageHeight;
  const heightLeft = imgHeight;

  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  doc.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
  doc.save('FileName.pdf');
});
```

Comment: tried html2canvas but all html content appears on the single page in the form of image. hence text cannot be selected.